# Debugging Express Server on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

I'm run an Express Server on Firebase Cloud Functions.

For example:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const express = require("express")

/* Express */
const app1 = express()
app1.get("*", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!")
})

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app1)
```

I'm using VScode as my code editior. I've tried everything but not sure how to debug my cloud function.

Here is what my VScode launch.json looks like:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to debug these function locally inside VScode?

Comment: this won't do it in vs code, but it will allow you to attach your node / express to the browser DevTools, which is also a much richer experience than debugging from the terminal console logs: run the following from the command line within your project directory `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions` and then within chrome DevTools, look for the little green 3D shape icon (it's on the left side), which, when clicked, will pop out another dev tools window debugging your backend functions. from there you could probably use the chrome debugger extension to get what you need within vscode

Comment: I've managed to get into debug mode with your way. Is there a way of making debugging the functions simpler. Right now it's very difficult to step into the chained functions to see what is going on (i.e. input and output). Is there a feature-rich debugger similar to IntelliJ

Comment: doing it right in the browser DevTools should work really well for change functions, break points, etc - the chrome dev tools docs are pretty well written, worth checking out! Good luck